# FireBase error signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm trying to use firebase in my app. I follow the steps online, with a new project.

when I try to write 
`FirebaseApp.configure()` in my appdelegate it gives me a 
`Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` 
if I delete it the app will run.

I do have my GoogleService-info.plist inside my project directory.

my podfile looke like this :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FireBaseTest' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to 
use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

 # Pods for FireBaseTest
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

Comment: Paste here the whole crash logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you set the target membership of the file.

1. Select `GoogleService-Info.plist` in the Xcode project navigator.

[image]

2. Enable the target in the right utilities pane.

[image]

Comment: This is the right solution. I had copied the file using Microsoft Visual Code but it wasn't in XCode editor, I had to drag it to the Xcode IDE to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in the same issue for 4 days I downloaded firebase the issue was I name google play list as *** GoogleService-Info-22.plist***. just remember don't put dashes rename it as
GoogleService-Info.plist